# Should I flag Android questions to be migrated to Android.SE?

Tags: discussion, flags

There are lots of questions regarding Android on SO even when there is an android SE site. So should I flag that questions to be migrated or just comment on question to tell OP to ask android on Android.SE next time or leave them as it is? Flagging questions can become a headache for moderators as they have to handle too much requests in this scenario because there are lots of android questions are being asked on SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android.SE is for Android users, not for developers. Questions about *development* of Android applications **should not be migrated**!

From their FAQ

> Android - Stack Exchange is for
>   enthusiasts, power users, and regular
>   people too using the Android operating
>   system.
>
> Android - Stack Exchange is not for
>   programming questions. Please ask your
>   developer questions on StackOverflow.

If you see a question about using Android that has nothing to do with programming, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: hmm..... I should have read the FAQs. :-\. Thanks for guiding me.